# AngularJs ng-repeat does not update after filter object gets updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am working on requirement where my filter object is keep getting changed and because of that i have to change ng-repeat on div.

html code :

```
 <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="model in models | filter:{ModelText : '!All models', ModelId: '!FilteredModelIds'}:true">
          <div class="well">
            <div class="media">
              <div class="media-object small"><i class="pp-car"></i></div>
              <div class="media-body">  
                <div class="text-box">                                      
                  <h3>{{model.ModelText}}</h3><span class="hr-small"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="dashboard-control clearfix">
                  <div class="simple-metric text-left sub-metric">
                    <div class="metric-title">Satisfaction score</div>
                    <div class="metric-number text-red">{{model.SatisfactionAvg}}</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="simple-metric text-left sub-metric">
                    <div class="metric-title">Total interviews</div>
                    <div class="metric-number">{{model.TotalInterviews}}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-standard">
                  <li> <a href="" class="text-black trigger-model-interviews">View interviews</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

here is the angular js code:

```
function getModelId() {
    dataFactory.getModelIdByFilter($scope.region, $scope.subregion).success($scope.handleSuccess).then(function (result) {
        $scope.FilteredModelIds = result.data;
    });
}
```

Model json :

```
[{"ModelId":0,"ModelText":"All models","Sequence":0,"TotalInterviews":0,"SatisfactionAvg":0.000000},{"ModelId":1,"ModelText":"A3","Sequence":20,"TotalInterviews":2062,"SatisfactionAvg":9.637245},{"ModelId":2,"ModelText":"A4","Sequence":30,"TotalInterviews":3106,"SatisfactionAvg":9.743721},{"ModelId":3,"ModelText":"A5","Sequence":40,"TotalInterviews":1863,"SatisfactionAvg":9.694041},{"ModelId":4,"ModelText":"A6","Sequence":50,"TotalInterviews":280,"SatisfactionAvg":9.642857},{"ModelId":5,"ModelText":"A8","Sequence":70,"TotalInterviews":46,"SatisfactionAvg":11.217391},{"ModelId":9,"ModelText":"Q5","Sequence":110,"TotalInterviews":3176,"SatisfactionAvg":9.503778},{"ModelId":10,"ModelText":"Q7","Sequence":120,"TotalInterviews":1355,"SatisfactionAvg":9.685608},{"ModelId":11,"ModelText":"R8","Sequence":130,"TotalInterviews":31,"SatisfactionAvg":10.064516},{"ModelId":12,"ModelText":"TT","Sequence":140,"TotalInterviews":408,"SatisfactionAvg":9.764705},{"ModelId":13,"ModelText":"A1","Sequence":10,"TotalInterviews":1087,"SatisfactionAvg":10.097516},{"ModelId":14,"ModelText":"A7","Sequence":60,"TotalInterviews":263,"SatisfactionAvg":10.190114},{"ModelId":15,"ModelText":"Q3","Sequence":105,"TotalInterviews":1045,"SatisfactionAvg":9.542583}]
```

on page load its showing proper data with filter. but on change of filtered object in my case FilteredModelIds, its not getting updated. any help is appreciated.

please let me know if i am worng here.

Thanks.

Comment: please show `models` object

Comment: @Maxim : I have updated models json object. please have a look.

Comment: You seem to be using models your in ng-repeat and not FilteredModelIds. Also, can we see your handleSuccess callback?

Comment: @dcodesmith If I place hardcoded value in place of FilteredModelIds I am getting filtered data. and for HandleSuccess its just logging data.

Comment: You should be setting `FilteredModelIds` inside your `handleSuccess`